# NSFileManager user/permission change on lock screen with password

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

When a password-protected iPhone is locked and apps are running in the background, do they run as a different user?

The following code works in the simulator all of the time, and on physical devices when the screen is not locked. When the screen is locked, it gives `error 13: operation not permitted`

```
 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Could not create data directory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"\n\n----Created OpenSenseData Directory----");
    }
}
```

The code is called as a result of CLLocationManager receiving a location update.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

The likely explanation is that apps run as a different user when in the background. If that's the case, is there a way to change the app permissions to allow file or directory creation when the screen is locked?

Comment: Have you tried with withIntermediateDirectories:YES ?

Comment: `dataPath` is under the root directory, but I did actually try that :/

When I am able to create the `dataPath` directory (in foreground mode), I later try to create files under it (in background mode + lock screen). This also results in `error 13`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the data permissions and is solvable by removing NSFileDataProtection from the parent directory. The initial parent directory has to be created while the application is in the foreground, and this **does** remove encryption from the file in question

```
NSDictionary *protection = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionNone forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:protection ofItemAtPath:parentDirectoryPath error:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: this helped us - we had had problem with accessing file when iPhone is locked (from Apple Watch) and this fixed it